# How do I "stretch" and "compress" a piecewise function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have Googled a few times and experimented on Desmos, but both attempts were to no avail, and now I come here. How is a piecewise function transformed to be "stretched" or "compressed"? What about other transformations?

Comment: Just do the usual techniques on each piece separately.  Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Yes, but do I multiply the x-value for the conditions? The values? Both?

Comment: If you are stretching / compressing vertically, nothing happens to the x values.  If you are stretching horizontally, then they distort to the same degree everything else distorts.

Comment: Okay thanks, I get it now.

Comment: I see what you're getting at.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you're getting at based on our comment discussion now.

The conditions also change.

For example, say we have $f(x) = x^2$ if $x > 10$.  Then $f(2x) = (2x)^2$ if $2x> 10$.  (Other pieces are irrelevant for this discussion and the same thing happens to them, so it's sufficient to consider one piece.)

Similar reasoning for horizontal translations.

The explanation behind this is... Think of our example function $f$ in words like this:

> $f$ of **the input** is equal to **the input** squared, if **the input** is greater than 10.

Now just replace **the input** with $x$ to get our original function.  Replace **the input** with $2x$ to get the compressed function.